# jquery url builder/parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, url, building

I'm searching for a jquery plugin for full URL manipulation (parsing, building).

Example:

```
var url = 'http://mypage.com/?param=1'
var params = $.getParams(url) # {param: 1}
var newUrl = $.newUrl(url, {param:2}) # 'http://mypage.com/?param=2'
```

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this jquery plugin https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser that I used once. But once you `console.log` `window.location` you will see that it is not so hard to do it your self.

I never tried this one: http://urldecoderonline.com/javascript-url-decode-jquery-plugin.htm but it seems it can build URL to.

Have fun

Answer (score 36):

To convert a JavaScript object into a URL parameter string you can use the jQuery `param` method:

```
$.param({a:1, b:"Test 1"}) // gets: "a=1&b=Test+1"
```

To parse a URL parameter string into a JavaScript object use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/171847).